# How to detect if a Solana program is invoked via CPI?

Tags: solana

A Solana program can be invoked by user or another program via CPI (cross program invocation), how to detect this in the context of the invoked program.

Comment: If you have access to that program then modify it to emit an event when the cpi instruction is invoked and then listen to that event wherever you want to check for the cpi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do this totally dynamically at the moment, but if you have access to the `Instructions` sysvar (https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/sysvars#instructions), you can do:

```
let instruction = solana_program::sysvar::instructions::get_instruction_relative(
        0, sysvar_instructions_account_info
    ).unwrap();
if instruction.program_id == my_program_id {
    // not CPI
} else {
    // CPI
}
```

Full source code at: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/79a8ecd0ac3b31ed25fa355fdb77b2c535347f78/sdk/program/src/sysvar/instructions.rs#L209